# How could a small human sized humanoid creature hang upside-down?

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology, humanoid

I am looking to have a creature which is basically a small human sized bat, something like man-bat from the batman series. It would ideally fly or at least glide and would regularly hang upside down.

Assuming a human like form, I am worried about muscle strength holding up that much weight while having a light enough frame to glide, as well as blood rushing to the head. I want it to be as scientifically acceptable as possible to the point where it starts interfering significantly with basic humanoid tasks, where it will have to be hand-waved.

What biological features could I use to justify a bat-like creature of this size? Particularly issues of weight, bone strength, and blood rush when upside down.

Comment: If it has lightweight bones, for gliding, then it requires much less strength to hang, right? Isn't your problem a self solving one?

Comment: Blood rush is a function of the arterial and venous valves. Giraffes have solved the same hydraulic problem for the opposite biological reason, so that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Locking joints in the limbs that they use to grip?

Comment: The giraffe thing was helpful @pojo-guy, I looked them up and it looks like quite a few features would work for this.

Comment: @Mołot Do you think the bones could still be strong enough to still walk around as a humanoid?

Comment: FWIW, I regularly hang upside down (for short periods - a few minutes or so) when exercising, and even do inverted situps.  E.g. https://www.livestrong.com/article/391106-hanging-upside-down-exercises/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sloths can do it.**

[image: sloth hanging upside-down]

from https://nation.com.pk/24-Apr-2014/sloth-guts-designed-for-hanging

> Three-toed sloths have a unique abdominal design - their innards fixed
>   to their lower ribs to avoid squashing the lungs while hanging upside
>   down, a study said Wednesday.

You could model your battish humanoid on sloths.  I seem to recall they have other adaptations for the upside-down life like an immunity to arthritis.

Comment: That would be useful for lungs, though I'm not sure it would fix the large amount of blood that would be affected by gravity.

Comment: @Wolfie but *something* helps sloths with their blood. You got a decent starting point, I guess you can just follow it.